# Use of '\' Before DOT in Domain Names in .htaccess Code

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, apache2

Many websites provide the .htaccess code to block spambots, spam referral, etc.

Some websites use '\' before the '.' in domain names. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} spamdomain\.com [NC,OR]

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer spamdomain\.com spambot=yes
```

But some websites use direct domain name. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} spamdomain.com [NC,OR]

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer spamdomain.com spambot=yes
```

Now I'm confused which code syntax is correct? Do both codes work fine? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the second argument to both the `RewriteCond` and `SetEnvIfNoCase` directives are *[regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)* (regex), not ordinary strings. Regex use a special syntax to define *search patterns*. In regex syntax, the dot/period is a special (meta) character that represents *any character* (except newlines by default). In order to match a literal dot (ie. disable its special meaning) you need to backslash escape the dot (ie. put a backslash before the dot).

So, a *regex* like `spamdomain\.com` matches the literal string `spamdomain.com` *anywhere* in the string being tested. (In the first example, it matches `spamdomain.com` *anywhere* in the `HTTP_REFERER` server variable.) Whereas a regex like `spamdomain.com` (where the dot is not escaped) would match `spamdomainAcom`, `spamdomainBcom`, etc. Because a dot matches any character.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} spamdomain.com [NC,OR]
> ```

Strictly this is incorrect. The regex matches more than is intended. However, in reality this might not be a problem if a literal dot is the only character that could appear in that position. (But in this case, the dot should be escaped.)

Reference:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifnocase

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So using '\' before the dot is correct.

Comment: Yes, in the examples you posted. It depends on whether the argument is a regex or an ordinary string. `.htaccess` code gets copy/pasted a lot so small errors can perpetuate. For example, you might sometimes see the dots escaped in the second argument of the `RewriteRule` directive (the _substitution_) eg. `RewriteRule ^foo$ http://example\.com/bar [R,L]` - in this case the 2nd argument is an ordinary string, not a regex, so the dots do not need to be escaped (although it doesn't break, because backslash escapes are still supported here).

Comment: You should read up about _regular expressions_ (a couple of links provided above). They are incredibly powerful for _pattern matching_. However, the syntax can be a bit cryptic in complex expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please also tell me which one of the following code is correct:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain\.com [NC,OR]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www.)?.*domain\.com.*$ [NC,OR]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*domain\.com/ [NC,OR]`

I found these 3 different formats on different websites. So which one should I use to completely block the referrer domain?

Comment: They would probably all "work". However, the last one would not match a request coming from `https` - however, if `domain.com` doesn't use `https` then it makes no difference. And the second one is overly complex. Of the three, the first one is perhaps preferable IMO (it's easier to read), but none are ideal - they are all very generic and could match too much. For example, all 3 would match `http://www.not-this-domain.com/`. That maybe OK for you, maybe not? It's your call. A pattern like `\.domain\.com` might be preferable. Generally, with regex, you should be as _specific_ as possible.

Comment: Note that a pattern like `domain\.com` is matched anywhere in the `HTTP_REFERER`. For example, it would match `http://example.com/path/to/domain.com`, which may not be desirable, but this is also very unlikely. (But all three of those examples would match this URL.)

Comment: Thanks. So I'll use the first one domain\.com to block the spam referrer domain.